# Xero CIS Contact Settings

Tags: xero-api

How do I create the CISSettings in a Contact via the API?

I tried using the endpoint :

```
POST https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts/xero-contact-id/CISSettings
{ 
  "CISSettings": [
    {
      "CISEnabled": true,
      "Rate": 20.0
    }
  ]
}
```

where xero-contact-id is the Xero ID
for an existing contact, but it return a validation error - Name cannot be blank

Comment: Does it make any difference if you post to the standard Contacts endpoint, without the CISSettings extension?

Comment: I just found out on the xero blogs that this is not possible. CIS settings have to be added manually at the moment.